# 80s (or earlier) book: Israel gets A-bombed and refugees come to UK

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember much of the plot, there was mass migration to the UK... I'm not sure if there WAS a nuke explosion or if there was proof that there was a weapon ready to explode and thus the Jewish people had to flee.

IIRC the action kept switching between desperate scenes in Israel and the ongoing chaos in the UK as the overwhelmed authorities tried to cope.

One section that sticks in my mind is a liaison officer turning up at some little village hall. There are rows and rows of trestle tables and lots of village volunteers dishing up heaped plates of ham salad to glowering Hasidic Jews.
Appalled, he asks if they are aware of kosher dietary   requirements, one of the volunteers brightly explains that of course they are, that's why they didn't do a roast pork meal instead.

I think(!) there are scenes of integration with British armed forces gaining several new regiments of well trained troops who are all seasoned combat veterans.

Update edit:
It's possible I have the meals wrong, they could have been sitting down to a roast pork dinner, with the volunteer saying there's nothing wrong with a nice ham salad